# How to evaluate a query based on the results of another query?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a query that returns the list of all distinct medical services from various facilities based on a field (services) in the master table (services_master).

```
SELECT DISTINCT unnest(string_to_array(LOWER(s.services),','))
FROM services_master as s
```

Which returns data like:

```
blood test
consultation
streptest
...
```

I then need to get other data from the table (and other tables) based on the user's selection of one of these services (as a drop down populated with the results of the first query).

My main query for all this data looks like this:

```
SELECT
    s.service_id,
    s.name,
    s.address,
    s.phone_num AS phone,
    s.lat AS x,
    s.lon AS y,
    s.website AS URL,
    s.services,
    h.hours,
    pc.cat_name as primary_category,
    sc.subcat_name as subcategory
FROM health.services_master s
LEFT JOIN health.business_hours h ON s.service_id = h.id
LEFT JOIN health.primary_category pc ON s.primary_cat_id = pc.cat_id
LEFT JOIN health.subcategory sc ON pc.cat_id = sc.pc_id
WHERE s.primary_cat_id = 2 AND s.sub_cat_id = 10 AND s.insur_id = 4;
```

Where the last where clause values will also be based on user input.

I've tried things like WITH blocks, though I have to admit the work I've done so far pushes my knowledge of postgres/sql queries.

Ideally, I would be able to evaluate the two queries concurrently (i.e. run service options list (query #1), and use this value in the second query as a where clause like: WHERE service_option = 'blood test').

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `in`?

```
where 'blood test' in (select unnest(string_to_array(lower(s.services), ','))
                      from services_master s
                     )
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for me. It returns either (which is false), or if I tweak it to search for, say "consultation", then I get all of the results in the database. 

The services field is a field of comma separated strings (i.e. bloodtest, consultation, x-ray, ...) may appear in one service. the creating the whole column into an array then unnesting it was my solution to querying it, though I feel this isn't working for 'IN'...